# Bash script for querying .txt

Tags: bash

I am new to bash and am trying to write a script that allows me to search a .txt for a keyword and have it print the line with that word on it. Here is what i have so far

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

fault=${1?Error: No Fault Given}
filedest=$(cat faults.txt)
line=$(wc -l faults.txt)

for list in $line

do

$filedest.awk '{if($1 = fault) then;
 awk '{print $0}'>"query.txt"}'

done
```

I keep getting this error:

```
line 12:Fault: command not found
line 12:Fault: command not found
```

any ideas as to what i've done wrong?

Comment: How about using `grep`? And your quotes do not match, you're missing `'`.

Comment: If you want to use a variable as input to a command, use `command <<<"$variable"`

Comment: What do you expect `for list in $line` to do? `$line` just contains the number of lines in the file, it's not something to loop over.

Comment: @Barmar I want to loop the if statment for as many lines that are in the text file. Have i done the for loop wrong?

Comment: Yes, it's wrong. `for i in $line` loops as many times as there are words in `$line`.

Comment: Use `for ((i=0; i < $line; i++))` to loop as many times as there are lines in the file.

Comment: But why do you need to loop? `awk` already loops over the lines in the file.

Comment: @Barmar oh i didn't know that. I assumed that it only did it for the first line. So I can get rid of the for loop and have awk on it's own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need for the `for` loop, since `awk` loops over the lines in the file itself.

Also `$1 = fault` should be `$1 == fault`. `==` is for testing, `=` is for assigning.

```
fault=${1?Error: No Fault Given}
awk -v fault="$fault" '$1 == fault' fault.txt > query.txt
```

Comment: I'm not getting errors. Only probelm is i'm not getting any output to query.txt

Comment: Make sure you use `==` not `=` in the test. Also, this performs an exact match of the first field, not it doesn't look for a pattern.

Comment: Update the question with sample file contents and the fault you're looking for.